How to guide the rag application to follow rules from a file and retrieve from another file?
I'm building a streamlit chat application that allows users (project holders) to boost their projects across different stages and help them prepare for presenting their projects within a startup programm, I have for this rag app , 40 pdfs (40 projects) and a guide.pdf (cookbook) , this guide shows the different stages and phases the project passes by and how to get financement and support from different entities and banks, I used langchain + faiss + ollama + llama 3.2 + hugging face embedding for this project (data is very private)! The app doesn't work well since I want the assistant to follow the rules provided in the guide and consider the details of each project to guide the user since the user is a project owner while leveraging the llama 3.2 capabilities to suggest solution that matches the guide and stages and also to zoom on the corresponding project.
